# How can i catch onclick event of Dynamically loaded control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a dropdownlist (on Page) which has OnSelectedIndexChange event thats Loads different  Control (ascx) dynamically each time ( with LoadControl Command) - into the page.

Each Control Has a Button(runat=server) and TextBox(runat=server).

When i click on the button - i cant get into the Onclick function .

How can i get into the OnClick Function  of the Ascx ?

I know that each SelectedIndexChange its makes postback - so i know i have to save something  in the viewstate. but i dont know how to save it and later get the values eneterd on the TexstBox. ( of Each ascx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event handler to the user control, like this:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
```

And in the click event of the button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ButtonClick != null)
        this.ButtonClick(this, e);
}
```

Then, from the page, you can get the click event like this:

```
<UC:MyUserControl ID="UserControl1" runat="server" OnButtonClick="UserControl1_ButtonClick" ... />

protected void UserControl1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Handle the click event here
}
```

If you're loading the controls dynamically, then you'll need to make sure the controls are rehydrated after postback, and emulate the code above by assinging the event handler through code:

```
MyUserControl ctrl = (MyUserControl)this.LoadControl("...");
ctrl.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl1_ButtonClick);
```

Comment: I need to recreate it on the post back BUT ALSO GET ITS VALUES .some friend told me its "control state" ...???

Comment: If you assign the same ID to the control when recreating it, the values should be repopulated for you.

Comment: @James: Deleted mine.  This is a much more complete answer

Comment: James , but if i press on the button , it goes throught pageload  will erase the UC  - so i wont be able to get to the OnClick...

Comment: You will be able to get the OnClick if you rehydrate the controls in OnPreInit or OnPreLoad, I believe. The button click event should fire after the page has posted back and the controls have been regenerated.

Comment: thanks James, still, i dont understant how to get the values of the textbox after i clicked the button ...since I can build them in the pre init but what about the values ive entered in the previous ascx's textbox ?

Comment: You're recreating them in the OnPreInit event, but the values are stored by control ID. When you recreate the control and assign the ID to it, the values corresponding to that ID are reloaded into the control.